# can kylin install on ubuntu (no hdfs) on machine1 connect to Hbase and Hive on another machine?

Tags: apache, hdfs, kylin

I have kylin installed on ubuntu on machine1 no hdfs and hive ,hbase on machine2 ,is connectivity possible between Kylin , hive and hbase ? if yes please let me know how ?

THanks,
Rahul S

Answer (score 0):

Kylin must be run on a single or a multi node cluster of hadoop, therefore the machine should have an instance of HDFS.